# What is UpdateListCompleted and why isn't it documented?

Tags: web-services, object-model

I've been messing around with the [SharePoint List web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists_members%28v=office.12%29) and I came across an event called `UpdateListCompleted`.

[image]

I thought this might be of some use for the project I am working on so I hopped onto MSDN's site hoping to learn a little more about this event.  I've come to expect piss poor documentation from MSDN, but I was surprised to find that their documentation doesn't even acknowledge that this event exists.

Googgling didn't turn up anything useful, so I'm wondering if anyone here has any info on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's the async callback for the `UpdateListAsync()` method.

Similar to the code in this post for the `UpdateListItemsAsync()` method:

http://neeleshkalani.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/sharepointlistoperationsfromsilvelight1/

## From MSDN:

```
public void SaveItemAsync(T item)
{
...
ListsSoapClient service = CreateListsService();
service.UpdateListItemsCompleted += new EventHandler<UpdateListItemsCompletedEventArgs>(service_UpdateListItemsCompleted);
service.UpdateListItemsAsync(ListName, batch);
}

void service_UpdateListItemsCompleted(object sender, UpdateListItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh537940.aspx